# htaccess - image url rewriting

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need to rewrite my images urls for better SEO using Timthumb.

I have this htaccess file (on Codeigniter) that It works, but when i past an url rewritten (es. http://www.example.com/products/loremipsum-450x600.jpg) It redirect to: http://www.example.com/resize/timthumb.php?src=http://www.moveshop.com/uploads/loremipsum.jpg&w=450&h=600

Is it possible to rewrite without redirect?
Thanks

-- 
My htaccess file is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /    
RewriteRule ^(products)/(.*)-([0-9]{1,4})x([0-9]{1,4}).(jpg) http://www.example.com/resize/timthumb.php?src=http://www.example.com/uploads/$2.$5&w=$3&h=$4 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Simply remove `R=301,` at the end of the rule.

Comment: @HashemQolami the `http://` part of the rule's target implicitly redirects

Comment: @JonLin Ah right.. missed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the htaccess file is on the same server as the destination (e.g. `www.example.com`, then you need to remove the host/scheme from your rule and the `R` flag:

```
RewriteRule ^(products)/(.*)-([0-9]{1,4})x([0-9]{1,4}).(jpg) /resize/timthumb.php?src=http://www.example.com/uploads/$2.$5&w=$3&h=$4 [L]
```

If they are not on the same server, then you need to reverse proxy, which means you must have mod_proxy loaded. You'll just need to replace the `R` flag with the `P` flag:

```
RewriteRule ^(products)/(.*)-([0-9]{1,4})x([0-9]{1,4}).(jpg) http://www.example.com/resize/timthumb.php?src=http://www.example.com/uploads/$2.$5&w=$3&h=$4 [P,L]
```